# Fastest ways to find duplicates

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, duplicates

So my interviewer showed me the following code,

```
struct test {
    uint8_t inuse;
    int32_t val;
};

#define MAX_LIST_SIZE 100
struct test list[MAX_LIST_SIZE];

int checkAndAdd(int32_t val) {
    for(int i=0; i<MAX_LIST_SIZE; i++) {
        if(list[i].inuse && list[i].value == value)
            return DUPLICATE;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<MAX_LIST_SIZE; i++) {
        if(!list[i].inuse) {
            list[i].inuse = 1;
            list[i].value = value;
            return ADDED;
        }
    }
    return EA_FAIL;
}
```

and asked me the following questions.

1. How to make that function faster?
2. What are the other fastest methods to find duplicates in array?

My answers were
1.

```
int checkAndAdd(int32_t val) {
    int32_t addedIndex = -1;

    for(int i=0; i<MAX_LIST_SIZE; i++) {
        if(list[i].inuse && list[i].value == value) {
            if (addedIndex != -1) {
                list[addedIndex].inuse = 0;
                list[addedIndex].value = 0;
            }
            return DUPLICATE;
        } else if (!list[i].inuse && (addedIndex == -1)) {
            list[i].inuse = 1;
            list[i].value = value;
            addedIndex = i;
        }
    }
    if (addedIndex)
        return ADDED;

    return EA_FAIL;
}
```

2. You can't have a faster duplicate check than O(n).

Were my answers correct? Please suggest any other good approaches and answer to 2. Thanks.

Comment: If you sort your `list` array, you could use a binary search with `O(log(n))` complexity.

Comment: Can you change the data structure?

Comment: @Ari0nhh Yes, I heard that. But for unsorted we don't have any other ways right?

Comment: @Schwern : yes we can

Comment: @Sarath There are a plenty of ways. You could transform a `list` array to the binary search tree (BST) for example. There is a huge Knuth tome about sorting and search algorithms.

Comment: Your function doesn't always return a value — the 'else' condition after the loop is missing.

Comment: Keep a record of the maximum entry in use; then you can speed up the search on an empty or nearly empty array dramatically.  Use a heap structure, perhaps (for O(logN) addition time, and search time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest, most general way to find duplicates is with a hash table.  That gives essentially constant-time access (with just a little added overhead to handle hash collisions).

If the set of integers is sufficiently dense, you could alternatively use an array indexed by value, but this is only practical if the percentage of holes is sufficiently small.

Comment: Do you have any code pointers please? also can you please check, the answer I gave for 1 is correct?

Comment: There are lots of hash table libraries around that you should be able to find pretty easily.  The main thing is to have a good hash function to minimize collisions.  If the values are uniformly distributed, then a simple `%` operation by the number of buckets will suffice.  But if that's not the case, then something more sophisticated may be needed.

Comment: Regarding your answer to question (1), the main advantage the changes give is they eliminate the need to search for an empty slot in the case where the value is new.  But it would be more efficient to simply save the index in the loop, and only update the entry if you fail to find it.  Either way, the run time isn't going to be that much better (and it could even be worse in the case of duplicates).  By the way, there's a bug, you need to add `return EA_FAIL;` to the bottom of the function.

Comment: There are a few other bugs.  You need to use a different, unique value to initialize `addedIndex`, since 0 is a valid index, and currently you cannot distinguish that case from the case where there is no added index.  The test at the bottom of the function is also backwards:  You only want to return `ADDED` if in fact there was an added index, not the other way around.  The check for `i` is unnecessary since it will always be true at that point.

Comment: Yes, the check for addedIndex, was a mistake. And the other check for i is redundant, agree.

Comment: Actually "index by value" is jus a degenerated hash-table.

Answer (score 2):

It's somewhat dependent on data patterns, but interpolative search is O(log log n).

Using binary search gives you O(log n), and for n <= 100, a maximum of 7 search steps, making interpolative search probably not worthwhile.

**Edit** to add side note: it's curious that the `struct` has `int32_t` but the argument to the function is plain `int`.  Probably not broken (are there any ILP64 systems out there?), but seems a bit sloppy.

Comment: can you please check, the answer I gave for 1 is correct?

Comment: You've already added the missing `return`.  There is still a bug though: a `uint8_t` holds values between 0 and 255 inclusive, and writing -1 into it sets it to 255.  The later comparisons will compare 255 against -1 (not against 255) and the result will always be that they are different.  If you change `addedIndex` to plain (signed) int, and fix the final test on it (to compare with -1), the routine will be correct.  It's not possible to say without testing whether it will be any faster than the original.

Comment: Thanks, Initially it was added to check against 0, when I changed to -1, missed to change the datatype. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to be able to quickly insert, delete, and avoid duplicates: what you want is a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28abstract_data_type%29) probably implemented with a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) where the key and value both point to the same data.

Hash tables inherently cannot have duplicates. They're *on average* O(1) for inserts, deletions, and lookups and O(n) on space. The only downside is there is no inherent order to the values. Since your original code does not appear to be preserving order that would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

If I gave you that as an interview question I might want to discuss Hashes etc and that would be a good sign, hashes are fundamental data structures but I'd be really looking to see if you could merge the two loops and you did that. Your second answer for a duplicate check is correct for lists ie O(n) but incorrect generally because it's dependent on data structure, if you use a hash it's O(1).

Please note that O(1) can sometimes and quite often turns out to be slower than O(n) in real life ie by the time you've hashed the thing to get a key, done the lookup and traversed the list of the hash structure you might have found the single item in the 5 you were looking for in a linked list.